# Transversal and complete intersection of hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

(a) Let $k<n$ and $F_{1},\dots,F_{k}$ be general homogeneous polynomials of degrees $d_{1},\dots,d_{k}$ in $n+1$ variables.

> Prove that the corresponding hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ intersect transversally at a smooth $(n-k)$-dimensional variety $X \subset \mathbb{P}^{n}$.

(b)
Let $k<n$ and $V_{1},\dots,V_{k}$ be transversally intersecting hypersurfaces.

> Prove that $\cap_{i=1}^{k} V_{k}$ is a complete intersection.

Comment: Hints: 

(a) use Bertini. 

(b) Think about the definitions.