# transversality of hypersurfaces and dimension of intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Y_1,\dots,Y_r$ be projective hypersurfaces of $\mathbb{P}^n$. Is it true that $Y_1,\dots,Y_r$ intersect transversally if and only if $\dim (Y_1\cap \cdots \cap Y_r) = n-r$?

**PS:** The motivation for this question is in my effort to understand why a transversal intersection of hypersurfaces is a complete intersection; see [Transversal and complete intersection of hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476765/transversal-and-complete-intersection-of-hypersurfaces-in-mathbbpn). This is stated by Harris (AG-First Course) below Exercise 17.17. The issue is that i have seen more than one definitions of transversality, and it is unclear to me if they are equivalent or not. For example the definitions of Harris and Shafarevich are different (which makes the answer/comment at the above link particularly unfortunate). At any case Harris defines $Y,X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ to intersect transversally (if i understand correctly) if $\mathcal{T}_{X,P}+\mathcal{T}_{Y,P}=\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{P}^n,P}$, for every point $P \in X \cap Y$.

Comment: What is your definition of transversal intersection?

Comment: @Mohan: I am sorry that i can not be very precise. I suppose the definition that i am interested in is the one that makes a transversal intersection of hypersurfaces a complete intersection. Do you know what that is?

Comment: Let me just stick to two factors: if I have two subvarieties of something smooth and the intersection has the right dimension and is reduced then the intersection is actually transverse at a general point. This is often all you need.

Comment: @Hoot: So let us take two affine hypersurfaces $Y_1=Z(f_1),Y_2=Z(f_2) \subset \mathbb{A}^n$. Is it not true that $Y_1 \cap Y_2$ is always reduced, since the ring of regular functions of $Y_1 \cap Y_2$ is $k[x_1,\dots,x_n] / I_{Y_1 \cap Y_2}$ and $I_X$ is always radical for any $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$? So isn't the "reduced" condition unecessary?

Comment: I'm working scheme-theoretically, so perhaps this is cheating.

Comment: @Hoot: I think i understand what you mean. You are viewing the variety as $Spec k[x]/(f_1,f_2)$. Ok, so does that mean that your statement is true for varieties if we removed the "reduced"?

Comment: I don't see how that follows. The scheme-theoretic intersection of varieties doesn't have to be reduced. I see that as a useful thing.

Comment: @Hoot: I think there is some confusion. Let me ask you: what do you mean by $Y_1 \cap Y_2$ being reduced as a projective variety? PS: i am currently trying to prove the statement that you made in your comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is not true!
If you take the conic $yz=x^2$ and the line $y=0$ in $\mathbb P^2$, their intersection  is of dimension zero but trivially these curves are not transverse at $(0,0)$ since they are tangent at that point.
This is essentially at the level of Euclid, 2300 years ago, who didn't have Harris's book to confuse him...

Comment: You're welcome, dear Manos.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $Y_1: y^2=x^3$ and $Y_2:y^2=-x^3$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$. We have that $Y_1\cap Y_2=\{[z; x; y]| zy^2-x^3=0=zy^2-x^3\}$, so $x^3=0$, and $zy^2=0$, so our points are $[0, 0, 1]$ and $[1, 0, 0]$, which is finite, and thus $dim_k(Y_1\cap Y_2)=0$, as we want. But $$(\mathcal{O}_{Y_1\cap Y_2})_{[1, 0, 0]}=k[y, x]_{(x, y)}/(y^2-x^3, y^2+x^3)=k[y, x]_{(x, y)}/(y^2, x^3)$$ So we can compute $I([1, 0, 0], \mathcal{O}_{Y_1\cap Y_2})=length_{\mathcal{O}_{[1, 0, 0]}}(\mathcal{O}_{Y_1\cap Y_2})=6$. So the intersection multiplicity is greater than one, so that the varities are not transverse at the origin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which definition of transversality are you using?

Comment: $X, Y$ is transverse if and only if for all irreducible components $W\subset X\cap Y$, $I(W, X\cap Y)=length_{\mathcal{O}_{W}}(\mathcal{O}_{X\cap Y})=1$. Since you didnt specify if you wanted this or the tangent space defintion, I just rolled with it!

Comment: I am sorry, i didn't even know that intersection multiplicity 1 is also know as transversal.

Comment: Ah, I should say though, this is slightly weaker than transverality in general, which states that the tangent bundle is the direct sum of the tangent bundles at points of intersection

Comment: Dear  Manos, don't worry about length and don't be sorry: "length" is an  unnecessary concept to answer your question.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes, with the addition of the background of the question, it is clear that I have taken the wrong approach.

Comment: Dear Chanler, your approach is definitely not wrong, only a bit sophisticated for a beginner. At a more advanced level consideration of length is quite valuable.